# How to uninstall DataStax OpsCenter agents?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

How can I uninstall DataStax OpsCenter agents from all/selected nodes in a cluster?

Comment: I think this question might get more answers at [sf].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By uninstalling the `datastax-agent` package manually, there is no way to do that via OpsCenter UI.

Comment: OK. But what is the command? I installed DataStax agents from OpsCenter UI, when I clicked on the "fix" link and provided creds. Is it a yum/rpm command on RHEL?

Comment: Yes, OpsCenter installs agent via packages, so it can be uninstalled using `rpm`. However, why do you want to uninstall agents instead of just stopping them?

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to uninstall to get a clean environment for my testing.